# how to return to top of for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, return

Maybe this is a dumb question but is there a way to return to the top of a loop?

Example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    if(i == 3)
        return;

    alert(i);
}
```

What you'd expect in other languages is that the alert would trigger 4 times like so:

alert(0);
alert(1);
alert(2);
alert(4);

but instead, the function is exited immediately when i is 3. What gives?

Comment: Could you give an example of 'other languages'?

Comment: What languages are you thinking of where returning in the middle of a loop makes the loop continue? It's not so in any language I know.

Comment: C# does not continue the loop - once you execute the 'return' statement, the function exits immediately, just as it does in javascript. C# also uses the 'continue' statement for the execution flow you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `continue` instead of `return`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TYLgJ/

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    if(i == 3)
        continue;

    alert(i);
}
```

If you wanted to completely halt the loop at that point, you would use `break` instead of `return`. The `return` statement is used to return a value from a function that is being executed.

**EDIT:** Documentation links provided by *@epascarello* the comments below.

- Docs for `continue`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue
- Docs for `return`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: continue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue
return: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: @epascarello - Thanks for adding the references. :o)

Comment: I guess mine was down-voted too. Down-voters should give a reason.

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, you can also label them:

```
OUTER_LOOP: for (var o = 0; o < 3; o++) {
  INNER_LOOP: for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (o && i) {
      continue OUTER_LOOP;
    }
    console.info(o, ':', i);
  }
}
```

outputs:

```
0 : 0
0 : 1
0 : 2
1 : 0
2 : 0
```